# First intersection of a ray and a set of circles?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry, line, intersection

I've been taught how to find an intersection between a line and a circle at highschool, so that's a pretty familiar concept to me. However, today, I'm looking to find a fast algorithm which, for

1. a ray: `(start_x, start_y, dx, dy)`, and
2. a `set` of circles: `(center_x, center_y, r)`

would find an intersection point (the one closest to the ray's origin) and the corresponding intersected circle, if it exists. No amount of googling has led me to an answer; for example, ray marching (as far as I know) is very expensive with respect to the amount of objects in the scene.

Possible solutions, none of which, I hope, are optimal (python pseudocode):

```py
def solve_0(ray, set_of_circles):
    for circle in set_of_circles:
        res = trivial_intersect(ray, circle)
        if res is not None:
            return ret
    return None
```

This solution is the absolute baseline. No optimizations, expected time taken is `n` times the constant corresponding to `trivial_intersect`. It is also the best solution I've come up with for the general case. Other solutions depend on some sort of preprocessing, which assumes that `ray` changes, but the `set_of_circles` doesn't.

```py
def preprocess_1(set_of_circles):
    r = find_optimal_grid_block_size(set_of_circles)
    grid = make_grid(set_of_circles, r)
    return grid

def solve_1(ray, set_of_circles, grid):
    for block in supercover(ray, grid):
        for circle in block:
            res = trivial_intersect(ray, circle)
            if res is not None:
                return ret
    return None
```

This solution can help reduce the amount of checked circles by a lot, however, it still is linear w.r.t. the size of `set_of_circles`.

And this is the last of my ideas:

```py
def preprocess_2(set_of_circles):
    voronoi = voronoi_polygons(set_of_circles)
    box = bounding_box(set_of_circles)

def solve_2(ray, set_of_circles, voronoi, box):
    current_voronoi_polygon = determine_starting_polygon(ray, voronoi)
    current_position = ray[:2]

    while current_position in box:
        circle = current_voronoi_polygon.get_corresponding_circle()

        res = trivial_intersect(ray, circle)
        if res is not None:
            return res

        for polygon_boundary_line in current_voronoi_polygon:
            res = trivial_intersect_2(ray, polygon_boundary_line)
            if res is not None:
                current_position = res.intersection_point()
                current_voronoi_polygon = polygon_boundary_line.get_other_polygon(current_voronoi_polygon)
                break
                
    return None
```

This solution utilizes the fact that only one circle can be inside a voronoi polygon, so if the intersection of `ray` and that `circle` fails, walk along the polygon boundary, find intersected line, enter the next polygon and repeat until the circle bounding box is exited. Since the polygon sizes would under "normal conditions" have sizes unrelated to the amount of circles in total, I expect this solution to perform even better than the previous one, because estimating a good grid size is hard.

So, please, can you come up with faster solutions? The solutions I posted are not perfect (and incomplete/buggy, I wrote them like this just to give the reader an idea behind what I'm thinking of)

If it helps, you can assume that the `set_of_circles` is fixed. Also, if it helps, you can assume that the circle radius is a constant.

Comment: I have a hunch that you can build a [cover tree](https://hunch.net/~jl/projects/cover_tree/paper/paper.pdf) on the centers and adapt Find-Nearest to do what you need by subbing ray-to-fixed-radius-circle distance for point-to-point distance.

Comment: Very cool @DavidEisenstat! I'll read that and then get back to you if it turns out you're right.

Comment: Are you expecting to find a solution that doesn't pre-process the circles somehow and is still sub-linear w.r.t. number of circles?

Comment: @AirSquid Definitely not. I hope you inferring that from my text is a singular case. Which part of my question body made you think so, please?

Comment: It is unclear from the body of the text what a normal instance of the problem is.  You discredit solutions that assume the ray changes, but the set of circles doesn't, yet at the end you say it is OK to assume that the set is fixed, and the 2nd solution is discredited for being linear.  So I guess I'm a bit unclear.  You do say at the end that the assumption of fixed set of circles is OK, which I think will help, but some edit about a normal instance of the problem might be of help.

Comment: Also, I think it is clear that determining *if* an intersection occurs is going to be much faster than determining the points of intersection.  (You said "point", which should be plural for almost every case, right)?  is it confirmed you want the algorithm to determine both points of intersection or is a T/F array sufficient?

Comment: @AirSquid The fact that I discredit those solutions is not because they assume anything, I discredit them because they are slow compared to what I hope to achieve! I'll add that info in in case that wasn't clear. Also, I actually only want the first point which is hit by the ray, but I don't mind comparing a bunch of points by their distance from the ray's origin.